# map action with struts.xml with multiple methods

Tags: java, struts2

I have seen many tutorials in which action has many methods other than execute

```
public class UserAction {

    public TestAction() {
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
      System.out.println("hello i aam action");

        return "success";
    }

    public String addUser(String name)
    {

     return "success";


   }

    public String listUser(String name)
    {

     return "success";


    }

    }
```

the action mapping is done like this

```
  <action name="addUser" method="addUser" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction">
  <result name="success" type="redirect">listUser</result>
</action>

<action name="listUser" method="listUser" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction"> 
  <result name="success">/register.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

I a unable to understand it.How listUser is getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this works because your mapping is pointing to methods (add, list) that do not exist. You have `addUser` and `listUser` in your action so your mapping have to point to the same methods.
Back to your question I have to say Struts2 has a feature that let's you pack a couple of methods into the same action. This is specially useful when you want to perform CRUD operations. One way is to explicitly predetermine the method you want to call in you mapping:

```
<action name="listUser" method="list" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction"> 
    <result name="success">/register.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If you point your browser to `http://yourDomainHere/listUser` your `list` method in your `UserAction` action will be executed. You can also use wildcard mapping here like:

```
<action name="*User" method="{1}" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction"> 
    <result name="success">/register.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In this case you can replace asterisk (*) with any method in your action. This mapping will take first placeholder ({1}) in the mapping as a method and call it. So you can point your browser to: `http://yourDomainHere/listUser` and `http://yourDomainHere/addUser` knowing the same mapping will handle both and your respective methods will be called.

**Edit for the comment**
I think I got your point. In the example you provided `listCustomer` is never called. It's the `addCustomer` that populates the `customerList` before sending `success` and since it has provided a getter method for the list, back in the page you can access it and iterate it and show the values.

Comment: in which condtion listUser will be called,i am unable to understand.addUser is getting called from form.When will listUser be called

Comment: @prerna In your mapping if the `addUser` is successful, it will send a redirect -which is defined in `type` attribute of the mapping- asking browser to request `listUser`.

Comment: actually i am following the tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hibernate-integration-example/  I am unable to understand the mapping of file in struts.xml

Comment: also <action name="*User" method="{1}" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction"> 
    <result name="success">/register.jsp</result>
</action>how will i redirect the request to listUser

Comment: @prerna Actually the config in the example is a basic configuration. If you're unable to understand that you need to take a look at some basic struts2 config help like this [guide](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/action-configuration.html). You might wanna be more specific about your question.

Comment: actually my doubt is the link of the tutorial.if ypu read that tutorial ,i am unable to understand how listUser is getting called

Comment: yes you got my point ,but if i want to use the wildcard method and want to call listCustomer,how will i do that in context to the tutorial   http://mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hibernate-integration-example

Comment: I gave you the resource in the comment above. Read it and you'll be fine.